# Div buttons not working on mobile phone

Tags: javascript, html, button

My website is

meesbuschman.com

The buttons work just fine on desktop, but on my android phone the buttons don't seem to work. It might be the fact that I'm using transitions or transform on my css, but I'm not possitive. I couldn't find anything on stack overflow.

```
$('#projectsBtn').click(function(){ 
    setWhite();
    growLogo();
    animateInfo(1);
    $('header').css('height', '20vh');
    $('.second-half').css('height', '80vh');


    $('.nav').css('transform', 'translateY(-100%)');
    $('.projects').css('transform', 'translateY(0)');

});


        <div class="nav">
            <div class="btn" id="skillBtn">
                <div class="small-border-bottum"></div>
                <div class="small-border-left"></div>
                <div class="small-border-top"></div>
                <div class="small-border-right"></div>

            <h2>My Skills</h2>
            </div>

            <div class="btn" id="projectsBtn">
                <div class="small-border-bottum"></div>
                <div class="small-border-left"></div>
                <div class="small-border-top"></div>
                <div class="small-border-right"></div>

            <h2>Projects</h2>
            </div>

            <div class="btn" id="aboutBtn">
                <div class="small-border-bottum"></div>
                <div class="small-border-left"></div>
                <div class="small-border-top"></div>
                <div class="small-border-right"></div>

            <h2>About me</h2>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="skills">
            <div class="btn" id="homeSkillBtn">
                <div class="small-border-bottum"></div>
                <div class="small-border-left"></div>
                <div class="small-border-top"></div>
                <div class="small-border-right"></div>

            <h2><i class="ion-chevron-up"></i></h2>
            </div>
```

Comment: Post the relevant code of the button including any functions that is triggered by it when clicked, css and html markup

Comment: The jQuery/JavaScript code for one of the buttons is there. That should be enough.

Comment: What exactly is not working? the click handler or the transition? If it is transition then add `-webkit-` for android

Comment: -webkit- is already added.

Comment: It seems like it's selecting the h2 inside of the button

Comment: Why DIV buttons instead of the standard HTML <button> element?

Comment: Because of the styling of the borders around it. Let me try it with normall buttons!

Comment: Changed it to buttons, still don't seem to work on my phone. So my guess is that it has to do with jQuery.